# Preventing rounding when reading dat file in Python

Tags: python, pandas

[original file(.dat)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4AYZ.png)

Above is the data file of .dat format.
I want to read this file in python. (In R, read.table worked well.)
I tried like below.

```
navy = pd.read_fwf("navy.dat", header = None, widths = [3,7,7,6,6,3,4,4,7])  
navy.columns = ['ID', 'ADO', 'MAC', 'WHR', 'CUA', 'WNGS', 'OBC', 'RMS', 'MMH'] 
navy
```

but the result is like below.
[python dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pGdUG.png)

It automatically rounds all the numbers in the original data!
But I don't want rounding.

What can I do?

Comment: check that pd.options.display.precision is not set to 0.

Comment: I checked that pd.options.display.precision is 6.

Comment: can you provide the actual .dat rather than a screenshot?

Comment: https://blog.naver.com/PostView.nhn?blogId=standup0819&Redirect=View&logNo=222250106943&categoryNo=1&isAfterWrite=true&isMrblogPost=false&isHappyBeanLeverage=true&contentLength=3188 

Thank you for your help!

Comment: no problem! Unfortunately I'm unable to reproduce your issue. I would recommend removing/reinstalling pandas to see if the issue resolves itself.